# How to check infinite loop in bash?

Tags: bash, infinite-loop

I have been trying to run an executable using a bash multiple times. There is a chance that this executable will fall into infinite loop, or segfaults. I know there is no try-catch in bash but we can bypass that using:

```
{ #try
    "myCommand" && "do what i want"
} || { #except
    "handle error"
}
```

But this is not capable of understanding infinite loop. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: That's not really a try/except.  It's more of an if/else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user `timeout` from the gnu coreutils.

Here a example for a timeout of 10 seconds

```
timeout 10s yourscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash can't tell you what's going on inside `myCommand` unless that loop sends a signal or modifies the system/environment. You could run your #try in the background `&`, then do something if it's still running after a certain amount of time. `$!` refers to the last backgrounded task.

Check out [Job Control](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/JobControl) in Bash.

```
myCommand && doWhatIWant &
sleep 10
ps $! &>/dev/null && kill $!
```